# What is the reason for this confusing log information about JavaScript objects in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I run this e.g. in jsFiddle:

```
function Animal() {
}

var animal = new Animal();

console.log(animal);
console.log(Animal.prototype);
console.log(animal.__proto__);
```

then I get these results (3x `Animal {}`) in the console of Chrome's DevTool window:

```
Animal {} (index):26
Animal {} (index):27
Animal {} (index):28
```

It is quite confusing in my opinion, because as we know only `Animal.prototype` and `animal.__proto__` point in this case to the same object. Or there is a reasonable cause to do it so?

Comment: Good question. What alternative would you propose?

Comment: Are you talking about the numbers? `26, 27, 28`?

Comment: @thefourtheye he is talking about log(animal) being shown as `Animal {}`. Perhaps the numbers should be removed to make it clearer.

Comment: @thefourtheye no :), I'm talking about 3x `Animal {}`.

Comment: @Tibos I have extended my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing it as an object, and showing all of its attributes inside of it. In this case, since there are none, it is showing up blank. However, if we add an attribute to the method, as such

```
function Animal() {
    this.foo="bar";
}

var animal = new Animal();

console.log(animal);
console.log(Animal.prototype);
console.log(animal.__proto__);
```

we get:

```
Animal {foo: "bar"}
Animal {}
Animal {}
```

EDIT: Misread the question

from the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto):
When an object is created, its **proto** property is set to reference the same object as its internal [[Prototype]] (i.e. its constructor's prototype object).  Assigning a new value to **proto** also changes the value of the internal [[Prototype]] property, except where the object is non–extensible.

Comment: The focus of the question is: Why are both `animal` and `animal.__proto__` of type `Animal`?

Comment: @Tibos Edited to reflect OP's post